# How to use cache in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

HI Everybody

I wanted to use caching in my application can any one help me how to start with and which is the best tutorials for the beginners

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say [Gregg Pollack's Scaling Rails series](http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails) is by far the best introduction into caching out there.

Comment: nice link ya i liked that videos which really help for beginner ...
thank you

Answer (score 4):

There's a quite exhaustive one on rubyonrails.org:

[Caching with Rails: An overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)